# Vi how to search for numbers

Tags: vi

I want to search for the occurrence of `100169200`

I typed `/100169200` but vi says `Pattern not found`

Edit

Since the question has been downvotes, I would like to make it clear that `grep` can find the number in the file, but `vi` does not.

Edit 2

For the sake of it, I download vim for windows, and it can find it. However vi in Solaris still does not work.

Comment: have you tried vimgrep?

Comment: I'm sorry Rosdi, but the number you are looking for is in another castle.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Was the question not valid? As I said.. grep can find it, but vi doesn't.

Comment: What if you try to search for anything else with vi? Can you find it? Try searching for a word or number or definitely see with your own eyes while in `vi`. If _that_ does not help, then you have some very strange problem. Oh, and about the downvotes: usually questions with only couple of lines in them tend to get downvotes easily. The more descriptive question, the easier to answer.

Comment: @Rosdi: The four votes to close as off-topic should give you a hint as to the downvotes.

Comment: Explain why grep can find but vi cannot.. if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Then the number isn't in the file you searched.

Comment: It is there when I `grep` it... I want to search in `vi` so that I can move back and forward.

Comment: You can search in `less` as well...

Comment: @SvenW thanks for the tip.. it works. vi still does not.